# How can I retrieve Shopify products via the REST API in a specific language without being admin?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Imagine a route on a Shopify shop like this: https://shopifyshop.com/products/some-product?lang=en - then I can access the product as JSON like this: https://shopifyshop.com/products/some-product.json?lang=en

However the main issue is that then the `?lang` parameter is not respected. How can I have it respect the language parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If the shop has the multiple languages enabled you can use the language code in the url like, example for Japanese:

shopifyshop.com/**ja**/products/some-product.json